# Trailing spaces with ntlk word tokenizer

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, whitespace, tokenize

How can I word-tokenize a sentence with nltk while preserving the information of the existence or not of a blank space after each token.

For instance, I would like to have for the following sentence:

```
import nltk
sent = u"A sentence that contains words but don't contain numbers"
tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(sent)
#tokens=['A',
# 'sentence',
# 'that',
# 'contains',
# 'words',
# 'but',
# 'do',
# "n't",
# 'contain',
# 'numbers']
```

the following list:

```
spaces = [True, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, False]
```

that tells for each token in the list `tokens` if there is a space after it or not in the original sentence `sent`.

Comment: If you are not married to NLTK, [spacy's](https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101) tokenizer makes this really easy to retrieve (you can just check on the `.whitespace` attribute. [docs](https://spacy.io/api/token)

Comment: I know, I used to use spacy and the .whitespace attribute, but what if I need to turn to nltk word tokenizer ?